# Silverstripe 4 change base url

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

where is it possible to change the baseURL on Silverstripe v4? Also after rewrite the base tag with http is set at the website. I would like to specify the baseURL itself, which will be applied to all pages (front site, admin).

Thanks for every tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set an alternating base URL like so:

**_config/config.yml**

```
SilverStripe\Control\Director:
  alternate_base_url: 'your/base/url/'
```

Comment: Can i change with this  <base href="*https*://www.example.net/"> ?

Answer (score 4):

It's good practice to set the base URL in the `.env` environment file so you can set separate base URLs for local development/ staging/ production etc.

We use the following line in the `/.env` file:

```
SS_BASE_URL="https://example.com/"
```

And then add the following to `/app/_config/mysite.yml`:

```
SilverStripe\Control\Director:
  alternate_base_url: '`SS_BASE_URL`'
```